# selecting items from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/6/) and in the view appointments tab there is a add timing button.When clicked on the same button ,a new rows gets inserted.I have a button save in the profile tab and on click it prints JSON value on the console.

**My problem**

Suppose I have clicked 2 times add timing button button and hence 2 new rows are inserted.Now I from the week day menu I have selected some day,entered totime and from time and selected hospital from the dropdown.Now when I click the save button(in the profiles tab) I want the JSOn but in my case hospitalID remain blank.So now I made variable and assigned `5` to it as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/8/)

But now I can not make `hospitalID=5` hardcoded because for now there is one hospital but in future I can add few more hospitals so based on the selected hospital from the drop down,I want the hospitalID

Comment: The problem you have right now is that you are storing a hospital name in `hospital`. I see no association of that name to an `id`. How that association is stored is important information.

Comment: @Origineil in the JSON I have all information like hospital name,id,fromtime,totime etc

Comment: It is worth noting, that a requirement (revealed via chat) is for the `JSON` representation of a `Schedule` to remain "as-is". So binding an object to `hospital` isn't an option.

Comment: As @Charlie has shown, and I alluded to in my previous comments, `hospitals` has to contain the `hospitalId`. The provided answer is the best step toward what you want. Assigning the hospital beyond that point depends on "how" you want to do it. I provided [a representative approach](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/7rHmH/) as an example. So the issue has become how you want/can allow the `hospitals` and the `Schedule` being interacted with to communicate with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hospitals` array needs to be an array of objects with two keys, one for the id and another for the hospital's name.

```
var hospitals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < schedules.length; i++) {
    hospitals.push({ name: schedules[i].hospital(), id: schedules[i].hospitalId() });
}
```

You can then specify the `optionsText` and `optionsValue` parameters in the `data-bind` for the dropdown. Also make sure to change the `value` parameter to use the `hospitalId` field in your schedule.

```
<select class="span8" name="hospital"
    data-bind="options: $parent.hospitalOptions,
               value: hospitalId,
               optionsCaption: 'Select Hospital',
               optionsText: 'name',
               optionsValue: 'id'" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
</select>
```

The `hospitalId` field is now updating in your model whenever you modify the dropdown, but the `hospital` field is not. I recommend turning that into a computed field that grabs the correct hospital name from a lookup based on the `hospitalId` value.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5nZRh/17/

Comment: A problem arises depending on how you want to lookup the value: 1) a `Schedule` doesn't have access to `$parent.hospitalOptions` 2) or the viewmodel doesn't have access to a "current" `Schedule`. Unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be refactored a bit. Either by passing in a reference to hospital options to the schedule, or by having the hospital options accessible under some global namespace.